# IntelliJ Startup Error "Cannot Lock System Folders"

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed [`IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 Community Edition`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) but when I run the application, it displays me the following error message:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.start(BuiltInServer.java:78)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:131)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:112)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:155)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:112)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:263)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:101)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:77)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:125)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:139)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:83)
    ... 29 more
```

The IDE doesn't boot up afterwards. It always worked flawlessly before but recently I have been getting this same error when trying to compile a `Java` project with `IDEA version 14.5`. After a clean installation of `15.0.1` it still doesn't work. It becomes quite obvious that the problem must be due to something I installed in the meantime but what could affect IntelliJ IDEA in such a way? I'm on Windows 10 and using [`AVAST!`](https://www.avast.com/index). I tried disabling my Antivirus and Firewall but it didn't help. I also submitted a bug report. Eclipse still runs and compiles Java code just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem to be AVAST! related. Maybe try to reinstall or deinstall it?
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146929
https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-34749

Comment: Yes, that was the cause. After uninstalling AVAST! and rebooting IntelliJ now works again as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Disable your firewall  or check your security settings.

Answer (score 0):

your firewall and antivirus program is blocking the android studio so remove antivirus program or add android studio.exe in allowed list this helped me

Comment: The asker states they already tried disabling their antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really easy. You just need to delete all .androidstudio* folders from appdata folder on your PC. Note that i don't know if this folder contains anything important.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is a problem with Avast security! I was using studio fine until one day my computer kept slowing down. I read that having 2 anti virus softwares can slow down your pc so i tried installing avast and just stick with Windows Defender. Avast cannot properly uninstall now the software is corrupted or something cause it wont start up. If you can get rid of Avast you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Windows works for me. But I think it is related to the firewall.

It happened after I closed a Windows Firewall dialogue asking me if another app (Everything.exe) can access the network (workplace, private or public) without response. After I restarted Windows, IntelliJ could launch normally.